# declaring bash variable from parsing JSON with curl and python

Tags: python, json, bash, curl

I have a URL endpoint that I want to retrieve a value from a JSON array.
If I use the following in a linux command line, it works perfectly:

```
curl -s http://10.10.1.10/api/ping | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["service"]'
```

Where "service" is the member I'm trying to access. 
I get a valid output such as `Collection Service`
I want to assign this output to a variable in a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICE= "$(curl -s http://10.10.1.10/api/ping)" | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["service"]'
```

However, this just gives me an error, saying that my JSON array is not a command.

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some odd quoting and bracing in your example.  I think if you just take the command that works to print the value you want and put it in $(...) you'll get what you want, so it would be like

```
SERVICE=$(curl -s http://10.10.1.10/api/ping | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["service"]')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `` ` `` backticks to capture a value from a command:

```sh
SERVICE=`curl -s http://10.10.1.10/api/ping | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["service"]'`
```

or put the `$(...)` around the whole command; `` `...` `` and `$(...)` are equivalent here:

```sh
SERVICE=$(curl -s http://10.10.1.10/api/ping | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["service"]')
```